# Jquery injecting html doesn't work. the ajax call is unstable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm kinda new in jquery & ajax. I have 2 problems. I have the following html hierarchy ;

```
<div id="tasks">

    <!-- I want to inject another div  task_element and change the values inside -->

    <div id="task_element">

        <section class="actionframe"> ...
        <nav class="commentsDetail">  ...       

    </div>

    <div id="task_element">
        ....
    </div>

</div>
```

The commented injection in html is handled by a html button click. I have the following jquery to handle the event;

```
$('.addTaskBtn').click(function() {

    if(!$('#add_task_name').val())
    {
        $('.dropinput nav').slideUp(300);
        return false;
    }
    else
    {           
        // call ajax
        var $task_name = $('#add_task_name').val();
        var $task_date_time = $('#add_task_date').val();        
        var $task_location = $('#add_task_location').val();
        var $add_task = 'add_task';
        var sent_data = { 
               "op": $add_task ,
               "task_name" : $task_name,
               "task_date_time" : $task_date_time,
               "task_location" : $task_location
        };      

        var $out = JSON.stringify(sent_data);

        $.ajax({

              type: 'POST',
              url: 'ajax_service.php',                    
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: 'json',
              data: $out,        
              success: function() {
                  //$('.dropinput nav').slideUp(300);
                  // append jquery div
                  //window.location.reload();
                  $('#add_task_name').val('');
                  $('#add_task_date').val('');
                  $('#add_task_location').val('');
                  $('.dropinput nav').slideUp(300);                                                                   
                  $('#tasks').closest('#task_element').prependTo('#tasks');
              },
              error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions ,thrownError) {          
                  console.log(xhr);
                  console.log(thrownError);
              }

         });                    
    }

});
```

The first problem is obviously I can't achieve the injection in html. The second problem is when I change code inside the success function, ajax_service became unstable to work. By unstable I mean that in first button click, it works correctly, but in the next click it doesn't work at all (vice versa) and throws internal server error.

Any ideas to solve the problem ?

Is it wrong to change ui in success function ?

P.S : I'm almost sure that ajax_service.php works correctly

EDIT : Based on comment, I'll add ajax_service.php ;

```
...some session variables and includes other php files here ...

$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($data, true);

if($data['op'] == 'add_task')
{
        $task_name = $data['task_name'];
        $task_location = $data['task_location'];        
        $task_date_time = $data['task_date_time'];
        $task_date_time = trim($task_date_time);

        if($task_date_time != "")
        {           
            $date_time = explode(" ", $task_date_time);             
            $task_date = "'".$date_time[0]."'";         
            $task_time = "'".$date_time[1]."'"; 

            if(trim($task_date) == "''")
            {
                $task_date = 'NULL';
            }
            if(trim($task_time) == "''")
            {
                $task_time = 'NULL';
            }       
            if( ($task_date == 'NULL'))
            {               
                $task_time = "'".$date_time[0]."'";
            }
        }
        else
        {           
            $task_date = 'NULL';
            $task_time = 'NULL';            
        }

        // 0 : history, 1 : today, 2 : later
        // compare browser time and task_date and define $time3 variable
        $task_time3 = 1;

        if(isset($task_name))
        {
            if($task_location == "")
            {
                $task_location = NULL;
            }

            $result_add_task = add_task($profile_id, $task_name, $task_location, $task_date, $task_time3, $task_time);
            if($result_add_task['result'])
            {
                $return['error'] = false;
                $return['msg'] = $result_add_task['description'];
                $return['op'] = 'add_task';
            }
            else 
            {
                $return['error'] = true;
                $return['msg'] = $result_add_task['description'];
                $return['op'] = 'add_task';         
            }

        }
        else 
        {
            $return['error'] = true;
            $return['msg'] = 'task_name is empty';
            $return['op'] = 'add_task';
        }

        echo json_encode($return);  
}
```

Comment: now, it works correctly in firefox & chrome. it doesn't work in safari. it drives me really crazy

Comment: well, I just noticed that when I directly access ajax_service.php, sometimes it says bad request (as I expected), sometimes it gives Server Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal server error hints at ajax_service.php not working correctly. Changing the ui in the success function is ok in principle. However, from your code  I cannot easily spot what you are tring to do. From what I understand from your comments you are trying to add a task in the following form to #tasks

```
<div id="task_element">
    <section class="actionframe"> ...
    <nav class="commentsDetail">  ...       
</div>
```

If that is the case you might want to create a new div and append it like so

```
var div = '<div id="task_element"><section class="actionframe">' + whatever_data_has_been_returned_from_server + '<nav class="commentsDetail"></div>'
$('#tasks').prepend($(div))
```

instead of this part of your code

```
$('#add_task_name').val('');
$('#add_task_date').val('');
$('#add_task_location').val('');
$('.dropinput nav').slideUp(300);
$('#tasks').closest('#task_element').prependTo('#tasks');
```

Comment: so, I need to create html in jquery. ok let me test that

Comment: the first problem is solved. I need a solution of ajax call being unstable.

Comment: please give us more code. msgmash.com is eager to find that bug, as well ^^

Comment: I've added ajax_service.php . The question is huge right now :D

Answer (score 2):

I think part of the problem might lie in this code

```
function() {
              //$('.dropinput nav').slideUp(300);
              // append jquery div
              //window.location.reload();
              $('#add_task_name').val('');
              $('#add_task_date').val('');
              $('#add_task_location').val('');
              $('.dropinput nav').slideUp(300);                                                                   
              $('#tasks').closest('#task_element').prependTo('#tasks');
```

I think this should be

```
function(data) {
              //$('.dropinput nav').slideUp(300);
              // append jquery div
              //window.location.reload();
              $('#add_task_name').val('');
              $('#add_task_date').val('');
              $('#add_task_location').val('');
              $('.dropinput nav').slideUp(300);                                                                   
              $('#tasks').prepend(data);
```

because you want to insert the data you get back from the php application into the list of divs under the #tasks div.  The data argument to the function holds the response data you get back from the server-side app (in this case, ajax_service.php).

Comment: PS. If there is a problem with ajax_service.php, we're going to need to see some code.

Comment: I've added ajax_service.php. It sometimes produce error and sometimes not with the same input.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out about the unstability of ajax call. I put `return false` after my ajax call and disable caching by `cache : false`